# Power BI IF Statement with two parameters from data in two columns from one table?

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I am trying to have a user in Power BI select a date. Then I want my visual to sum all insurance policies' premium with an effective date ON or BEFORE that selected date AND an expiration date AFTER that selected date. This will show all policies currently in force. How can I do this?

In my head it sounds like an IF statement sorta like:

IF Policy[EffectiveDate] <= Calendar[Date] AND Policy[ExpirationDate] > Calendar[Date] Return [Current Year Premium]

I have no idea how to write this so it works though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a measure like this

```
Measure =
VAR _selectedDate =
    MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Policy[Premium] ),
        FILTER (
            Policy,
            Policy[EffectiveDate] <= _selectedDate
                && Policy[ExpirationDate] > _selectedDate
        )
    )
```